# Was it possible to get an audience with Emperor Palpatine?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious

Most Kings/Emperors in real life or fantasy have/had a throne room and part of the reason for the existence of said room is to meet with other dignitaries, officials, royals etc., but also to grant audience (from time to time) to commoners(*), as was customary for Byzantine emperors, French Kings and so on.

So my question is: **Did Emperor Palpatine ever grant audience to a commoner?**

I don't remember this ever happening in the movies so far, so EU answers are acceptable. Also, Luke in RotJ was admitted in the throne room after the Emperor's "request", so it doesn't count. Furthermore, Vader was the Emperor's head-honcho, so he also doesn't count.

(*) Commoner=Not royalty, not a member of the imperial navy or any other high ranking official.

Comment: Are you asking if he kept office hours for drop-in visits?

Comment: Not even if they were a very low-ranking cadet?

Comment: Does Vader count? He's not a member of the imperial navy or other high ranking official. As far as I'm aware he holds no *official* title at all.

Comment: I'm asking what the question says: if it was possible for anyone outside royalty, officials etc to see the Emperor and if there was any such case recorded.

Comment: Well Vader was his henchman, so I guess he also doesn't count. I'll edit to clarify this.

Comment: what do you mean by 'commoner'? In the new canon book "Thrawn" - Thrawn and his human translator Cadet Eli Vanto are brought before the Emperor. Neither are high ranking at the time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Probably not

The canon novel *Tarkin* indicates that the Emperor did not go out in public:

> Tarkin adopted a questioning look. “What rumors? And why are you whispering?”
>
> Tenant glanced around before answering. “About a mobile battle station. A weapon that will—”
>
> Tarkin stopped him before he could say more, glancing at Amedda in the hope that he and Tenant were, in fact, out of the Chagrian’s range.
>
> “This is hardly the place for discussions of that sort,” he said firmly.
>
> Tenant looked chastised. “Of course. It’s just that … You hear so many rumors. People are here one day, gone the next. And **no one has laid eyes on the Emperor in months. Amedda, Dangor, and the rest of the Ruling Council have taken to dispatching processions of Imperial skylimos simply to maintain an illusion that the Emperor moves about in public.**” He fell briefly silent. “You know they commissioned an enormous statue of the Emperor for Senate—I mean, Imperial Plaza? So far, though, the thing looks more terrifying than majestic.”
>
> ...
>
> As Nils Tenant had reaffirmed, there were as many rumors circulating about the Emperor as there were about Darth Vader. **The fact that he rarely appeared in public or even at Senate proceedings had convinced many that the Jedi attack on him had resulted not only in the ruination of his face and body, but also in the death of the sanguine politician he had been before the war, betrayed by those who had served him and had supported the Republic for centuries.** Some Coruscanti even confessed to having fond memories for ex-chancellor Finis Valorum, about whom they could gossip to no end. **They yearned to see the Emperor strolling through Imperial Plaza or attending an opera or officiating at the groundbreaking of a new building complex.**
>
> <sub>**pp. 67, 76**</sub>

It's difficult to prove a negative, but it's doubtful that the Emperor would grant an audience to a "commoner" if he avoided being seen in public for months at a time.

Comment: Snoke is Palpatine confirmed.

Comment: @Edlothiad .......?!

Comment: @NKCampbell neither liked being out in public, and there's some sort of running online thing that everyone claimed Snoke _must be_ Palpatine